# How to upgrade from react-router to react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-dom

If i want to upgrade from `"react-router": "^2.0.0"` to `"react-router": "^4.0.0","react-router-dom": "^4.0.0"`.
My structure should be like this:

1. Main Component :is a container component for every thing (the
   parent).
2. Nav Component :is used to navigate among my other child components and this component should appear always.
3. Child Components: Examples , About ,Test. where Test is the Default.

---

My old code which works as expected is like this :

-App.jsx

```
var {Route, Router, IndexRoute, hashHistory} = require('react-router');

        ReactDOM.render(
          <Router history={hashHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={Main}>
              <Route path="about" component={About}/>
              <Route path="examples" component={Examples}/>
              <IndexRoute component={Test}/>
            </Route>
          </Router>,
          document.getElementById('app')
        );
```

-Main Component is like this :

```
var React = require('react');
var Nav = require('Nav');

var Main = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Nav/>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

module.exports = Main;
```

-My Nav Component is like this :

```
var React = require('react');
var {Link, IndexLink} = require('react-router');

var Nav = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active" activeStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Test</IndexLink>
      <Link to="/about" activeClassName="active"  activeStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>About</Link>
      <Link to="/examples" activeClassName="active" activeStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Examples</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

module.exports = Nav;
```

---

I try to upgrade like this:

-App.jsx

```
var { BrowserRouter, Route } =require('react-router-dom');

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
   <div>
       <Route path='/' component={Main} />
       <Route path='/Test' component={Test}/>
       <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
       <Route path='/examples' component={Examples}/>
   </div>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

-My Main Component has no changes

-My Nav Component is like this :

```
var React = require('react');
var {Link, NavLink} =require('react-router-dom');
var Nav = ()=>{
  return(
    <div>
    <NavLink activeClassName="active" activeStyle={{fontWeight: 'Bold'}} to="/Test">Test</NavLink>
    <NavLink activeClassName="active" activeStyle={{fontWeight: 'Bold'}} to="/about">About</NavLink>
    <NavLink activeClassName="active" activeStyle={{fontWeight: 'Bold'}} to="/examples">Examples</NavLink>
    </div>
  );
}

module.exports = Nav;
```

---

I face the following problems :

- The Test Component isn't the default like before.
- The Main Component doesn't behave like a parent.
- When i refresh the browser on Examples, i get the following error :

> http://localhost:5000/examples net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to change your App.jsx module, so it's rendering only Main component, because now you can move your router in there. React Router v4 is no more rendering it's routes to props children. Now you need to declare it at specific place you want it to be rendered.

App.jsx

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <Main/>,
      document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Main component

```
var React = require('react');
var Nav = require('Nav');
var { HashRouter, Route, Switch } = require('react-router-dom');

var Main = (props) => {
   return (
     <HashRouter>
        <Nav/>
        <Switch>
           <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
           <Route path='/examples' component={Examples}/>
           <Route component={Test}/>
        </Switch>
     </HashRouter>
   );
}

module.exports = Main;
```

- So now your Main component can behave like parent.
- If you remove path attribute for Route component, it will behave like default. Also you might noticed I've added Switch component. It should assure one route is rendered exclusively. You can check detailed info in [manual](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch).
- Before, you had used hashHistory for your Router, now you can do the same using HashRouter. This should resolve error you get.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but you have removed `{props.children}` how the children had rendered !? and if i want to center the children, should i add css classes on each child component (examples, about, and test) or can i do that in the `main` component ?

Comment: Now Route is a regular component, as soon it matches path, it will be rendered. It's not using `{props.children}` anymore. So inside switch component one of the Route components will match and render component provided in attr. You can center your components in Main, just wrap your `Switch` with `div` and apply CSS styles to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Could you illustrate the difference between `<BrowserRouter>`  and `<HashRouter>` please

Comment: `BrowserRouter` uses the HTML5 history API, for that you would need also to configure your server properly. When `HashRouter` uses hash portion of URL. e.g. '/examples' with BrowserRouter and '/#examples' with HashRouter